# Encoding.GetEncoding can't work in UWP app

Tags: c#, encoding, win-universal-app, uwp

I need to encode some text files for native characters.

In my Windows 8.1 Store app, I could use `Encoding.GetEncoding()` method normally:

```
Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254")
```

But in UWP app, I got this exception:

> Additional information: 'windows-1254' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.

I don't know how to make it work by using **`Encoding.RegisterProvider`** method, any ideas?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

We need to use the CodePagesEncodingProvider to register extended encodings included in that specific provider. See [CodePagesEncodingProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.codepagesencodingprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) Class

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254");
```

Ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encodingprovider(v=vs.110).aspx

> The .NET Framework Class Library provides one static property,
>   [P:System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.codepagesencodingprovider.instance(v=vs.110).aspx), that returns an
>   EncodingProvider object that makes the full set of encodings available
>   on the desktop .NET Framework Class Library available to .NET Core
>   applications.

The related thread in MSDN forum: [Encoding.RegisterProvider -- How to use?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/9c6cbef9-aa41-47bd-9c2d-a49f0952a545/encodingregisterprovider-how-to-use?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: Interesting, don't know this change, I will test it later, have you tried that in UWP app?

Comment: Surely you ought to mention that this can only work on a UWP app that runs on a desktop?

Comment: In order to use this you need this nuget package: `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages`. And you need to target UWP, of course. I am not sure if that works on all devices, but maybe it doesn't, as the previous comments suggest...