# Encodings with dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core

How to read file with ANSI encoding or another encoding with dotnet core?
If I do this:

`var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");`

it fails with exception:

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Additional information: 'windows-1251' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.

Comment: `var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);`?

Comment: Also you spelled "Windows" wrong, probably doesn't help!

Comment: yep. I wrote wrong. But it not help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579661/encoding-getencoding-cant-work-in-uwp-app

Comment: @CodeCaster, I think it must help.