# get all Text Encoding in universal windows app

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, uwp

I want to make windows application that convert text encoding of Txt file.
so I need to get all text encoding supported by windows.
I look for `Encoding.GetEncodings()` Method but it is not exist in Universal Windows Apps.
so I try to get encoding by CodePage, and this is my code:

```
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        List<string> errors = new List<string>();
        int[] code_page = { 0, 1200, 1201, 1252, 10003, 10008, 12000, 12001, 20127, 20936, 20949, 28591, 28598, 38598, 50220, 50221,
        50222, 50225, 50227, 51932, 51936, 51949, 52936, 57002, 57003, 57004, 57005, 57006, 57007, 57008, 57009, 57010, 57011, 65000, 65001 };
        for (int i = 0; i < code_page.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                list.Add(Encoding.GetEncoding(code_page[i]).EncodingName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { errors.Add(code_page[i] + "\t\t" + ex.Message); }
        }
        }
```

And I have this result:

#### First list (Encoding)

- Unicode (UTF-8)
- Unicode
- Unicode (Big-Endian)
- Unicode (UTF-32)
- Unicode (UTF-32 Big-Endian)
- US-ASCII
- Western European (ISO)
- Unicode (UTF-7)
- Unicode (UTF-8)

#### Errors list

- 37___No data is available for encoding 37. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.
- 437__No data is available for encoding 437. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.
- 500__No data is available for encoding 500. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.
- ...etc

and my question is there any way to get all windows text encoding.

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579661/encoding-getencoding-cant-work-in-uwp-app

Comment: I'm sorry.
Thanks.