# Is there a way to force the UWP RichEditBox use only UTF encoding when the user types?

Tags: html, encoding, uwp, richtextbox, rtf

I am trying to convert the contents of a UWP `RichEditBox` to HTML.

For that purpose, I've tried using the `RtfPipe` library (https://github.com/erdomke/RtfPipe). From the looks of it, this library has a problem on UWP, due to the fact that not all encodings are defined on that target framework. (This is the error you get, if you are interested: [Encoding.GetEncoding can't work in UWP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579661/encoding-getencoding-cant-work-in-uwp-app), but the accepted answer seems not to be the best option on all platforms - I haven't even managed to make the suggested fix compile, so it might not be valid anymore)

Now, as a way of avoiding this from happening, I am wondering whether there is a way to force the control to always use one of the UWP-defined UTF-variants for encoding the data when the user types his text.
Because, now, when I type into it, I get things like that:

```
{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1253\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1032{
....
\pard\tx720\cf1\f0\fs23\lang1033
```

...that make the library throw exceptions.

I guess, if I manage to make it not use ASCII code pages, things will be great.
After taking a look at the control properties though, I do not see something I could use. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is the error you get, if you are interested: Encoding.GetEncoding can't work in UWP app

As you described, there is an inner error thrown when using this package with UWP app. `System.ArgumentException: 'Windows-1252' is not a supported encoding name`, by testing on my side, which is thrown by the code line `public static readonly Encoding AnsiEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");` of [`RtfSpec.cs`](https://github.com/erdomke/RtfPipe/blob/master/RtfPipe/Parser/RtfSpec.cs) when `UpdateEncoding`.

It seems like `Windows-1252` may not be supported in UWP from the error details,also see [this similar thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dd5fca6d-7293-4446-b625-defaeb251e53/uwpgetencoding-windows1252-is-not-a-supported-encoding-name-windows-10-universal-prooject?forum=winappswithcsharp). You could use UTF instead as you want, for example, have a change on the library with following then it will work (testing demo [here](https://github.com/sunteenwu/CRichEditBox)).

```
public static readonly Encoding AnsiEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

> I haven't even managed to make the suggested fix compile, so it might not be valid anymore

[`Encoding.RegisterProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.registerprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) method should be work, but it only support `UWP` or `.NET Framework 4.6`, it does't support the `Portable Class Library`. The `RtfPipe` library you mentioned is `Portable Class Library`, so that you cannot use `Encoding.RegisterProvider`. [`Encoding.GetEncoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a3kf7c(v=vs.110).aspx) method supports `Portable Class Library`, details please check the version information of the two classed.

> I guess, if I manage to make it not use ASCII code pages

[RTF](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm) itself uses the ANSI, PC-8, Macintosh, or IBM PC character set to control the representation and formatting of a document, you may not able to change that. Consider to update the library to resolve the [issue](https://github.com/erdomke/RtfPipe/issues/2) for UWP.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did (even before I read your answer): I have copied the library code in one new UWP DLL project of mine and made sure it built correctly. I have installed the nuget package `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages` in order to use `System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance` that is defined inside it and then it worked great.

Comment: I guess this will also work in windows phones and XBoxes, right? Not sure why people say it won't work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33579717/964053)... Maybe I test it with the VS simulator later, although I never managed to make it start in the past... If you ask me, MS must find a better control to allow formatted text edit. Or at least renovate the existing one and provide an out of-the-box convertion between HTML and RTF.